# Loading CSV & JSON Converted DataFrames into PostgreSQL Database Failure

Tags: sql, python-3.x, pandas, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm working on an ETL assignment. I have two data frames:
1 came from a CSV file, the other came from an API call that was converted to a JSON file.
I am currently trying to upload the data frames into my PostgreSQL database but I keep getting errors that I do not understand no matter how much I google them.

Here's the code and error:

```
## Connecting to my local database [changed items (<>) to cover my info]
    rds_connection_string = "<username>:<password>@localhost:5432/<database name>"
    engine = create_engine(f'postgresql://{rds_connection_string}')

## Attempt to load CSV converted Dataframe into database
    inspect_transformed.to_sql(name='Ny_Inspection', con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False)

##Error message (same error for JSON attempt)

    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    InvalidTextRepresentation                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    ~\Anaconda3\envs\MyPyEnv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py in _execute_context(self, 
    dialect, constructor, statement, parameters, *args)
       1223                     self.dialect.do_executemany(
    -> 1224                         cursor, statement, parameters, context
       1225                     )

    ~\Anaconda3\envs\MyPyEnv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\postgresql\psycopg2.py in 
    do_executemany(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context)
        772         else:
    --> 773             cursor.executemany(statement, parameters)
        774 

    InvalidTextRepresentation: invalid input syntax for integer: "NKA"
    LINE 1: ... "Zip_Code", "Boro", "Grade") VALUES ('THE PALM', 'NKA', 'JF...
                                                             ^


    The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

    DataError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-15-0683923e3eec> in <module>
    ----> 1 inspect_transformed.to_sql(name='Ny_Inspection', con=engine, if_exists='append', 
    index=False)

    ~\Anaconda3\envs\MyPyEnv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in to_sql(self, name, con, schema, 
    if_exists, index, index_label, chunksize, dtype, method)
       2711             chunksize=chunksize,
       2712             dtype=dtype,
    -> 2713             method=method,
       2714         )
       2715 

    ~\Anaconda3\envs\MyPyEnv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py in to_sql(frame, name, con, schema, if_exists, index, index_label, chunksize, dtype, method)
        516         chunksize=chunksize,
        517         dtype=dtype,
    --> 518         method=method,
        519     )
        520 

    ~\Anaconda3\envs\MyPyEnv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py in to_sql(self, frame, name, if_exists, index, index_label, schema, chunksize, dtype, method)
       1318         )
       1319         table.create()
    -> 1320         table.insert(chunksize, method=method)
       1321         if not name.isdigit() and not name.islower():
       1322             # check for potentially case sensitivity issues (GH7815)

    ~\Anaconda3\envs\MyPyEnv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py in insert(self, chunksize, method)
        754 
        755                 chunk_iter = zip(*[arr[start_i:end_i] for arr in data_list])
    --> 756                 exec_insert(conn, keys, chunk_iter)
        757 
        758     def _query_iterator(

    ~\Anaconda3\envs\MyPyEnv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py in _execute_insert(self, conn, keys, data_iter)
        668         """
        669         data = [dict(zip(keys, row)) for row in data_iter]
    --> 670         conn.execute(self.table.insert(), data)
        671 
        672     def _execute_insert_multi(self, conn, keys, data_iter):

    ~\Anaconda3\envs\MyPyEnv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py in execute(self, object_, *multiparams, **params)
        986             raise exc.ObjectNotExecutableError(object_)
        987         else:
    --> 988             return meth(self, multiparams, params)
        989 
        990     def _execute_function(self, func, multiparams, params):

    ~\Anaconda3\envs\MyPyEnv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py in _execute_on_connection(self, connection, multiparams, params)
        285     def _execute_on_connection(self, connection, multiparams, params):
        286         if self.supports_execution:
    --> 287             return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
        288         else:
        289             raise exc.ObjectNotExecutableError(self)

    ~\Anaconda3\envs\MyPyEnv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py in _execute_clauseelement(self, elem, multiparams, params)
       1105             distilled_params,
       1106             compiled_sql,
    -> 1107             distilled_params,
       1108         )
       1109         if self._has_events or self.engine._has_events:

    ~\Anaconda3\envs\MyPyEnv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py in _execute_context(self, dialect, constructor, statement, parameters, *args)
       1246         except BaseException as e:
       1247             self._handle_dbapi_exception(
    -> 1248                 e, statement, parameters, cursor, context
       1249             )
       1250 

    ~\Anaconda3\envs\MyPyEnv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py in _handle_dbapi_exception(self, e, statement, parameters, cursor, context)
       1464                 util.raise_from_cause(newraise, exc_info)
       1465             elif should_wrap:
    -> 1466                 util.raise_from_cause(sqlalchemy_exception, exc_info)
       1467             else:
       1468                 util.reraise(*exc_info)

    ~\Anaconda3\envs\MyPyEnv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py in raise_from_cause(exception, exc_info)
        397     exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb = exc_info
        398     cause = exc_value if exc_value is not exception else None
    --> 399     reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
        400 
        401 

    ~\Anaconda3\envs\MyPyEnv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py in reraise(tp, value, tb, cause)
        151             value.__cause__ = cause
        152         if value.__traceback__ is not tb:
    --> 153             raise value.with_traceback(tb)
        154         raise value
        155 

    ~\Anaconda3\envs\MyPyEnv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py in _execute_context(self, dialect, constructor, statement, parameters, *args)
       1222                 if not evt_handled:
       1223                     self.dialect.do_executemany(
    -> 1224                         cursor, statement, parameters, context
       1225                     )
       1226             elif not parameters and context.no_parameters:

    ~\Anaconda3\envs\MyPyEnv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\postgresql\psycopg2.py in do_executemany(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context)
        771             extras.execute_batch(cursor, statement, parameters)
        772         else:
    --> 773             cursor.executemany(statement, parameters)
        774 
        775     @util.memoized_instancemethod

    DataError: (psycopg2.errors.InvalidTextRepresentation) invalid input syntax for integer: "NKA"
    LINE 1: ... "Zip_Code", "Boro", "Grade") VALUES ('THE PALM', 'NKA', 'JF...
                                                                 ^

    [SQL: INSERT INTO "Ny_Inspection" ("Restaurant_Name", "Building", "Street", "Zip_Code", "Boro", "Grade") VALUES (%(Restaurant_Name)s, %(Building)s, %(Street)s, %(Zip_Code)s, %(Boro)s, %(Grade)s)]
    [parameters: ({'Restaurant_Name': 'A&H DELI', 'Building': '431', 'Street': '7TH AVE', 'Zip_Code': 10001.0, 'Boro': 'Manhattan', 'Grade': 'A'}, {'Restaurant_Name': 'ANTOJITOS ECUATORIANOS', 'Building': '3398', 'Street': 'FULTON ST', 'Zip_Code': 11208.0, 'Boro': 'Brooklyn', 'Grade': 'A'}, {'Restaurant_Name': 'I LAND FISH & GRILL', 'Building': '7911', 'Street': 'FLATLANDS AVE', 'Zip_Code': 11236.0, 'Boro': 'Brooklyn', 'Grade': 'B'}, {'Restaurant_Name': 'CAFE LAFAYETTE', 'Building': '80', 'Street': 'LAFAYETTE STREET', 'Zip_Code': 10013.0, 'Boro': 'Manhattan', 'Grade': 'A'}, {'Restaurant_Name': 'FLY BAR', 'Building': '4224', 'Street': 'COLLEGE POINT BLVD', 'Zip_Code': 11355.0, 'Boro': 'Queens', 'Grade': 'A'}, {'Restaurant_Name': 'ACE HOT BAGEL & DELI', 'Building': '25305', 'Street': 'NORTHERN BOULEVARD', 'Zip_Code': 11362.0, 'Boro': 'Queens', 'Grade': 'A'}, {'Restaurant_Name': 'PIZZA CHEF', 'Building': '564', 'Street': 'WEST  235 STREET', 'Zip_Code': 10463.0, 'Boro': 'Bronx', 'Grade': 'A'}, {'Restaurant_Name': 'MANCORA BAR & APNA MASALA INDIAN CUISINE', 'Building': '344', 'Street': 'E 6TH ST', 'Zip_Code': 10003.0, 'Boro': 'Manhattan', 'Grade': 'A'}  ... displaying 10 of 196370 total bound parameter sets ...  {'Restaurant_Name': 'DINOSAUR BAR-B-QUE', 'Building': '2276', 'Street': '12 AVENUE', 'Zip_Code': 10027.0, 'Boro': 'Manhattan', 'Grade': 'A'}, {'Restaurant_Name': "MCDONALD'S", 'Building': '5713', 'Street': 'CHURCH AVENUE', 'Zip_Code': 11203.0, 'Boro': 'Brooklyn', 'Grade': 'A'})]
    (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/9h9h)
```

I read the documentation and I do not understand the issue or know how to fix it... please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a type mismatch issue you need to either alter the column or change the incoming data

Do check the type of the 2nd column you are inserting into it must be integer and you are inserting some NKA value which is string